# What is the correct way to call a localhost api url on my deployed nginx app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

## Edit

A more succinct summary of my problem and issue is the following:

I have a qa tester who will need to verify features on the qa server
by checking visually the application by hitting the `app.com` domain and then will need to make a series of postman api requests against that same server. The problem are that the domain names are not the same.

So after seeing that the code works as expected with `app.com`, the qa-tester will hit the following domains

```
differentdomain_one.com/users   ----> localhost
differentdomain_two.com/blogs   ----> localhost
differentdomain_three.com/      ----> localhost
```

These domains are handled by app.com but need to be called explicitly in postman by `differentdomain_one.com` etc. I want these domains to be localhost mapped to localhost. The `app.com` will hit its appropriate A record and the apis will hit localhost. How can I do that?

#####Edit Complete

I have a production rails app that has the following domain:

```
app.com
```

Now in this rails application lies api code that hits another url endpoint. That endpoint looks like the following:

```
api.app.com
```

So in production, users can execute the following endpoints:

```
api.app.com/users
api.app.com/users/1
api.app.com/users/1/posts
```

etc. etc.

Now for my development environment I have it set up so that my url for development is the traditional port 3000 endpoint. The app in development is the following:

```
app.local:3000
```

Accompanying this url, the api url is the following:

```
api.app.local:3000
```

And with postman I can make the following calls:

```
api.app.local:3000/users
api.app.local:3000/users/1
api.app.local:3000/users/1/posts
```

Its worth noting though that I have in my `/etc/hosts` this entry for the api.

```
127.0.0.1 api.app.local
```

By having this entry in `/etc/hosts`, I am able to make calls with Postman to make local development calls.

The problem now that I am having is that I need to do the same for my qa testers in a deployed environment only for qa. I have deployed a rails application to an ec2 instance. That environment has the following url mapped to an IP.

```
1.2.3.4.5 qa.app.com
```

I can see the rendered app by clicking on `qa.app.com` perfectly. The problem now is the api part. I figured that what needs to be done is just like my dev environment, I need to place something  in my `/etc/hosts` but I am not sure what though.

Here is what I tried first. I tried to place the following in `/etc/hosts`.

```
1.2.3.4.5 api.app.local
```

From what I can tell, this will tell nginx to immediately map `api.app.local` to the registered ip `1.2.3.4.5` without a dns lookup. But now I'm confused about Postman. By doing the below api call, I get an error saying that postman could not connect.

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://api.app.local:3000/users.
```

I understand that I am not on localhost so maybe the port is the problem. However, if I make this api call without the port, I get the same error:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://api.app.local/users.
```

This makes me wonder how I should call the api from this qa environment. Is this even the right approach or would a `proxy_pass` directive be more appropriate? This is my nginx conf file for inspection.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name 1.2.3.4.5;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env qa;
    root /home/ubuntu/app/public;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

}

Do I need to add the `api.app.local` into the `server_name` block? I would think not because I have it in `/etc/host`. If someone has familiar in this area of expertise, I would greatly appreciate how I can achieve hitting the api through nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Don't map `qa.app.com` in `/etc/hosts` on your QA server.

Your first need to set CNAME in the domain registrar to map subdomain to the IP address.

Then you need to change your nginx configuration from `server_name 1.2.3.4.5;`
 to `server_name qa.app.com;` and restart nginx.

P.S. It may take little time mapping DNS to the IP.

If you want to call local API from QA server or any other machines, you need to use tunneling utilities like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Help has realy been tough to come across regarding this issue. However, I'm not sure if your answer would apply to my most recent edit. Could you please take a look at my edit at the top of the question? I would greatly appreciate your help. My concern is not to proxy pass but hit completely different domain host endpoints. Can ngrok accomplish this?